# How to create (explode) separate rows using two array columns in presto/SQL

Tags: sql, presto, trino

if we have two arrays with same shape. How do we create/explode the separate rows for each element in array associated with other element in second array in Presto SQL.

For eg.,

```
|           Array1         |           Array2          |
| ------------------------ | ------------------------- |
| [0, 1, 34, 55, 68, 100]  | [40, 10, 30, 50, 60, 88]  |
```

Desired result

```
| Column_a | Column_b |
| -------- | -------- |
|     0    |    40    |
|     1    |    10    |
|    34    |    30    |
|    55    |    50    |
|    68    |    60    |
|   100    |    88    |
```

I tried using

```
SELECT Column_a, Column_b FROM a
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(Array1) AS t (Column_a)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(Array2) AS t (Column_b)
```

But it gives output with every other array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UNNEST`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) allows flattening several arrays at a time:

```sql
SELECT Column_a, Column_b 
FROM a
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(Array1, Array2) AS t (Column_a, Column_b)
```

If length of the arrays differ then the shorter one will be padded with `null`'s

Answer (score 1):

you can try this approach:

```
SELECT
    unnested_array1 AS Column_a,
    unnested_array2 AS Column_b
FROM
    (SELECT UNNEST(Array1) AS unnested_array1, UNNEST(Array2) AS unnested_array2) AS t;
```